# Missing Production Certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, ios-provisioning

We have several apps published to the App Store since the last 5 years and up until now I have been able to sign them with the correct developer and distribution certificate.

Today when I checked the iOS member center, I saw that almost all of my provisioning profiles status are set to Expired. Usually when this happen I just tap on Edit and then tap on Done and they change to active. However, when I tap on Edit now, it shows a message that reads:

*No certificates are available.
You need a certificate to configure a provisioning profile.*

When I navigate to Certificates > Production I see a message that asks me to create a new certificate.

This is the first time I am encountering such an issue and clueless if I would have to create a new certificate as mentioned and if doing so will cause any issues to our users.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Development and distribution certificates expire after 12 months. You need to create a new certificate and edit the provisioning profiles to use the new certs.

Creating new certificates will not affect current users.

Not sure why you haven't run into this in 5 years though. Is it possible somebody was creating the updated certs? Or perhaps you were using Xcode to automatically generate them?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just recreated the certificate and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the App IDs stay the same, renewing expired or revoked certificates will not affect your users. Even the production certificate has an expiration date and would need to be renewed from time to time anyway.